# Updating dimensions when focus is lost from any of 9 columns

Tags: c#, form, event-handling

How can I write this more pretty?

```
private void _detailSpread_OnCellFocusChange(object sender, CellFocusChangeEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.SourceCol == _detailSpread.GetColNumber("article"))
        UpdateDimensionData(_detailSpread.GetColID(e.SourceCol), _detailSpread.Rows[e.SourceRow]);
    else if (e.SourceCol == _detailSpread.GetColNumber("account"))
        UpdateDimensionData(_detailSpread.GetColID(e.SourceCol), _detailSpread.Rows[e.SourceRow]);
    else if (e.SourceCol == _detailSpread.GetColNumber("dim_1"))
        UpdateDimensionData(_detailSpread.GetColID(e.SourceCol), _detailSpread.Rows[e.SourceRow]);
    else if (e.SourceCol == _detailSpread.GetColNumber("dim_2"))
        UpdateDimensionData(_detailSpread.GetColID(e.SourceCol), _detailSpread.Rows[e.SourceRow]);
    else if (e.SourceCol == _detailSpread.GetColNumber("dim_3"))
        UpdateDimensionData(_detailSpread.GetColID(e.SourceCol), _detailSpread.Rows[e.SourceRow]);
    else if (e.SourceCol == _detailSpread.GetColNumber("dim_4"))
        UpdateDimensionData(_detailSpread.GetColID(e.SourceCol), _detailSpread.Rows[e.SourceRow]);
    else if (e.SourceCol == _detailSpread.GetColNumber("dim_5"))
        UpdateDimensionData(_detailSpread.GetColID(e.SourceCol), _detailSpread.Rows[e.SourceRow]);
    else if (e.SourceCol == _detailSpread.GetColNumber("dim_6"))
        UpdateDimensionData(_detailSpread.GetColID(e.SourceCol), _detailSpread.Rows[e.SourceRow]);
    else if (e.SourceCol == _detailSpread.GetColNumber("dim_7"))
        UpdateDimensionData(_detailSpread.GetColID(e.SourceCol), _detailSpread.Rows[e.SourceRow]);

    _detailSpread.Validate();
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A shorter version would be to create an anonymous array in the `if` statement combined with a collection initializer where you will add all of the column names and call the extension method `.Any` to check if any item matches the predicate:

```
if (new[] {"article", "account", "dim_1", ...}.Any(item => e.SourceCol == _detailSpread.GetColNumber(item)))
{
    UpdateDimensionData(_detailSpread.GetColID(e.SourceCol),
        _detailSpread.Rows[e.SourceRow]);
}
```

Answer (score 22):

I don't do C# so pardon the syntax, but you should be able to reduce the amount of code by using a for loop over a string array with your column names.

Again I don't do C# but in Java you could do something like this:

```
for(String col : new String[]{"article", "account", "dim_1", ...}) {
    if (e.SourceCol == _detailSpread.GetColNumber(col)){
        UpdateDimensionData(_detailSpread.GetColID(e.SourceCol), 
                            _detailSpread.Rows[e.SourceRow]);
        break;
    }
}
```

I would consider extracting the string array to a constant.

Or if your table is static you could just use a `HashSet` (or whatever it's called in C#):

```
// Somewhere in a constructor or static initializer
HashSet<Integer> focusChangeColNumbers = new ...;
colNumbers.put(_detailSpread.GetColNumber("article");
colNumbers.put(_detailSpread.GetColNumber("account");
...


// Then do:

private void _detailSpread_OnCellFocusChange(object sender, CellFocusChangeEventArgs e)
{
    if(focusChangeColNumbers.contains(e.SourceCol)){
        UpdateDimensionData(_detailSpread.GetColID(e.SourceCol), 
                            _detailSpread.Rows[e.SourceRow]);
    _detailSpread.Validate();
}
```

Note that this is going to be \$O(1)\$ in the number of columns where the other options are \$O(n)\$ in the number of columns.

Another option (if the API permits, I have no idea) is to simply turn it around:

```
String[] focusColNumbers = new String[]{"article", "account", "dim_1", ...};
if(focusColNumbers.contains(_detailSpread.GetColName(e.SourceCol))){
    ...
}
```